# Можно ли запустить AngleSharp в Parallel.Foreach()

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Собственно сабж.
Нужно вытащить содержимое определенного тэга. Но страниц очень много и приходится обрабатывать их в  `Parallel.Foreach()`.
Пытался использовать `AngleSharp`, но получил проблему.
На большом количестве данных - исключение, на малом - не обрабатывает все данные.
Использовать `lock(o)` - потерять все преимущества.
Можно ли что-то сделать?

код:

```
Parallel.ForEach<LogDataVM>(ParcedData, (item) =>
            {
                GetTitle(item);

             }
            });

private void GetTitle(LogDataVM item)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.UnloadedFile.Url)) return;
        string tempurl = item.UnloadedFile.Url[0] == '/' ? Domen.DomenName + item.UnloadedFile.Url : item.UnloadedFile.Url;
        // Используем библиотеку AngleSharp
        try
        {
            Url url = new Url(tempurl);
            IDocument document;
            var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
                document = BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(url).Result;


            item.UnloadedFile.Title = document.Title;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new WebException(e.Message);
        }

        return;
    }
```

Comment: Вы не пишете, какие ошибки вы получаете. Может, это серверные ошибки от того, что вы обрушиваете двести потоков на сервер в секунду.